# Application of Fubini's theorem, lebesgue integral with product measure

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Show that for $f(x,y)=xy/(x^2+y^2)^2 $ for $ x,y \neq (0,0) $ and $ f(0,0)=0$ , the iterated integrals $\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1fdxdy  $ and $\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1fdydx$ coincide but that the double integral $ \int_{(-1, 1)^2} f d\mu$ does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

**The double integral does not exist**: using the polar coordinates,
$$
f(r,\theta) = \frac {A(\theta)}{r^2}
$$
and $$
\int_0^1 \frac {dr}{r^2} = \infty
$$

**The nested integral exist and coincide:** as $f(x,y) = f(y,x)$
I just have to prove the existence of the integral.
For $y>0$ fixed, 
$|f(x,y)| = \frac {|y|}2 \frac {2|x|}{(x^2 + y^2)^2}$
and
$$
\int_0^1 \frac {2x}{(x^2 + y^2)^2} dx
= \int_0^1 \frac {dU}{(U + y^2)^2} < \infty $$
and the inner integral has value 0, because $f(-x,y) =- f(x, y)$
!